# Connect cloud of points using OpenCV VIZ WMesh

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have a cloud of points in form of `Mat pointCloud(numOfDataPoints, 1, CV_32FC3)`. I am currently visualizing them using VIZ by using `viz::WCloud`.

I aim to connect the points in a cloud using lines or texture. I came across `viz::WMesh`, but am unable to use it.

It would be great if someone could provide some example how to use it. 
I tried using individual line widgets to connect points but it makes it very slow. Any other idea how to do it fast would be very helpful.

[image: Point Cloud Image]

Comment: Can you make this a little more specific? Maybe add the code that doesn't work, and explain how it exactly doesn't work? As it is, this is quite a broad question and could even be considered as "asking for an off-site resource", which is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey Amit, I wondered if you could share how the points are displayed, because I cannot replicate the above.